# Java System.setProperty Proxy

Tags: java, proxy

I am using this to authentificate to HTTP URL to get a JSON String

```
        HttpURLConnection inputStream = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();


        inputStream.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEncoded);
```

I need to use

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port);
```

to build my connection through a proxy. Now my new proxy needs authentification as well. Is it correct that I just need to add

```
System.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEncoded);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying with a `https` target, below code would be required. You can check `Authenticator` to make it more exhaustive than the minimal one provided below.

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pwd".toCharArray());
        }
    });
```

In case you're dealing with a `http` link, the below itself would be sufficient by adding `Proxy-Authorization` header to the request -

```
inputStream.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEncoded);
```